# Pulling users information from mysql table, using a $_SESSION or $_GET, PHP?

Tags: php, session, url

I am building a website for fun, I have a question and don't know where to look for the answer.

On a successful login, I am setting a session with the user's email and then using that to pull the necessary data from mysql. Is there any downsides to doing it like this? Or would it be better appending the user's email to the url?

How safe is it to store the user's email in a session? I thought about hashing the session, but that would also mean hashing it when they signup/ login etc, so even if the session file could be viewed it would take some serious hacking to get the email?

And how common is it for people to hash, both password and email? Is it really needed??

Comment: If you are really worried about security, you could serve up your page as an https using SSL/TLS protocol. That way, you limit the risk of anyone 'spying' on your network traffic. Passwords are generally protected this way, email addresses less so. You'll need an SSL certificate and access to your webserver's configuration files to do this though.

Comment: use a framework don't go reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Pete855217: Actually you only reduce the risk of the one spying to understand what is being transmitted.

Comment: @maz4ever you also don't learn anything using frameworks.

Comment: @Nobody: Which is the risk you're concerned about.

Comment: @Pete855217: None. I just wanted to state that https does not magically prevent those who can from sniffing your traffic. It just prevents them from understanding, though there might be a point in future where they are able to understand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to add any personal information to an URL for authorisation purposes. I would go with the hashing of the user's credentials, with a pseudorandom salt.

You should *really* salted-hash at last the password the very second you get it the first time - and never use the clear-text pw ever again.

Comment: I am hashing passwords, I was asking about the users email being used in a session opposed to appending it to the url for the task of getting data from the mysql table.

Comment: Don't do this. It is an easy attack vector - I could just try a list of likely email addresses, e.g. yours, and would be in.